# How to send image via bluetooth from PC to android using C#

Tags: c#, file, bluetooth, transfer

I am able to do data transfer between PC and android via bluetooth. But now i want to send image files of size around 80KB. When i send the image, only a part of it gets transfered but not 
completely. Does anyone know how to achieve that? I am using TCP and working in C# platform.

```
        string fileName = "send.png";

        string filePath = @"C:\Users\Asus 53s\Desktop\";      //path
        byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);

        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
        byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData,0);
        fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData,4);
        fileData.CopyTo(clientData,4+fileNameByte.Length);

        sendMessage(clientData);

              }

    public Boolean sendMessage(byte[] msg)
    {

        {
            if (!msg.Equals(""))
            {
                UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
                NetworkStream stream = me.GetStream();
                stream.Write(encoder.GetBytes(msg + "\n"), 0, (msg).Length);

                stream.Flush();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Without posting any code how do you expect anyone to know what could be at fault!

Comment: Sorry, I have pasted the code that i am using right now.

Comment: How much of the image is recieved.  You might have to send it in small chunks.  What have you done to figure out the reason your code is not working.  Depending on the revision of bluetooth it can be pretty unreliable.

Comment: 10KB out of 60 KB is getting transfered. Tried to send in chunks. But the first chunk only is being sent repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a binary object first to a string and then converting it to UTF-8 is not a good idea...  Lots of bad things may happen in the conversions.  (And there's also a bug in `sendMessage`.)

Why not just do:

```
public Boolean sendMessage(byte[] msg)   
{   
   stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);   
   stream.Flush();   
}
```

If you really need that final "\n", then add before the Flush:

```
stream.WriteByte((byte)'\n');
```

Whilst we're on the subject of UTF-8, why are you presuming that the filename will only contain ASCII characters??  Change that code to:

```
byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
```